# How to create a COM dll using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, dll

How do I create a COM dll using Visual Studio 2008? What are the custom settings needed for creating the dll? That dll should be used in Microsoft Navision(ERP PACKAGE).

Comment: Thank god you made it wiki :) ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a class library. In the project properties, open the dialog where you can change assembly information and mark the "Make assembly COM-visible" checkbox (sorry, don't know the exact name of the option, using German VS 2008).

Then, add the following attributes to any class that should be used from Navision:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("YOUR-ID-GOES-HERE")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
public class ComVisbleClass
{
    ....
}
```

I suggest that you also manually assign Disp-IDs to the public methods and properties using the `DispId` attribute. Otherwise, inserting new public methods or properties may break Navision functionality, as the Disp-IDs may be changed upon compilation.

Navision would then refer to the old Disp-IDs which may now "point" to different methods. This is a PITA to debug and solve, so use the `DispId` attribute from the start.